# setting a HashMap in request Or ActionForm from JSP

Tags: hashmap, jsp-tags, struts-1, struts-tags

Strut 1.3 Application  :

Iam setting a hashMap into request & using it to create a checkbox list at JSP.
Iam creating a chekbox with name="checkboxname", and I have associated variable (of type String[]) in ActionForm with name "checkboxname". This will retain the values of the checked checkbox.

Now when when use submit the form . the form is not having the HashMap value set. How to make hashMap Available in the Form generated by submitting .

Generally we go for hidden elements to persist value for still submit  (But this work in case of String ). 
But, I am really not sure how to save a hashMap in HTML form elements.

Is there any other way to achieve this.

Short : I want to create Or persist a Hashmap which request attribute to use it in the  submitting action  class